# Why is Cumulative "Density" wrong?

Tags: probability, terminology

CDF stands for cumulative distribution function. However, it is "loosely" referred to as Cumulative Density many times. As i write this question, I have a suggestion toolbar on this page that lists over 10 questions with the words "Cumulative Density" in them.

I came across [this question in this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84174/what-is-the-closed-form-expression-for-cumulative-density-of-a-zero-mean-unit-v) post where a comment clearly highlights how the word "cumulative" contradicts "denisty" and "cumulative density function" is a term that shouldnt be used. However, I came across the term in many other posts and even answers in this forum like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84174/what-is-the-closed-form-expression-for-cumulative-density-of-a-zero-mean-unit-v) and 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/what-is-cdf-cumulative-distribution-function).

Unfortunately, I do not have privileges to comment on the post which suggests the difference between the two. Hence a new question. Can someone explain the contradiction in details please. Thank you.

Comment: I have never hear the term density used in the context of CDF. I would stick with distribution to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_density_function

Comment: Right. i saw the wikipedia link before. I wanted to know what the contradiction is. May be with the help of an example.

Comment: It is more about the use of the language than a counterexample. Density refers to a point and distribution refers to a range. I don't think there is anything more profound to it than that.

Comment: The term *density* in general refers to the amount of something per unit length/area/volume, e.g. mass density, charge density, etc. The probability density function tells you, literally, the density of probability. It is something you integrate over a region to obtain the actual probability. The cumulative distribution function, on the other hand, tells you the actual integrated probability between $-\infty$ and the point in question, so it is not a density: it is not something you can integrate over a region to obtain a sensible quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard "cumulative density" used before. People are saying that it is a contradiction.  To see why, it helps to look at the definitions of cumulative distribution function (CDF) and probability density function (PDF).

Assume $X$ is a continuous random variable.
The CDF is 
$$F(x) = P(X\leq x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(x) \, dx.$$
It is the integral of the PDF $f(x)$ up to some value $x$.

- The CDF $F(x)$ is "cumulative" because it accumulates the total area under the PDF from $-\infty$ to $x$. The CDF says something about $X$ over an *entire interval* $(-\infty,x]$.
- The PDF $f(x)$ is the "density" because it tells us how how likely it is that $X$ will be near $x$.  More quantitatively, $f(x) \, dx \approx P(x < X < x + dx)$. The PDF says something about $X$ *locally at each point* $x$.

Comment: This makes the most intuitive sense about the "contradiction". Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P) $ be a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ a random variable. The distribution function of X is $$F(x) = \mathbb P\circ X^{-1}(-\infty,x] = \mathbb P(X \leqslant x). $$ If $F$ is a continuous function, in which case $F$ is actually absolutely continuous (due to monotonicity and boundedness), so F is differentiable almost everywhere. A continuous function f which extends F' is called a probability density function of X.